# Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have initiated an app `cdk init app --language typescript` and ran the command `cdk synth` and now  I am running `cdk bootstrap` but it throws this error:
`Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment` as I want to create cloudFormation changeset

Comment: What's the name of your profile on the AWS credentials file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve: 'Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK or through the environment'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963515/how-to-resolve-unable-to-resolve-aws-account-to-use-it-must-be-either-configu)

Answer (score 1):

solved when I did `cdk bootstrap aws://yourAccountNumber/us-east-1`
you can find your aws account number in AWS console under your name which its the same as Account ID, and the region flag mean any region you want to deploy your service

Answer (score 0):

the name of config and credential file should be the same